# Why text input field disappearing (html , php)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

------------code 1 ------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type ="text" value="default text" name="someName">
        <input type ="submit" value ="Submit" > 
    </form>
    <?php echo "Entered data is -->".$_POST["someName"]; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

----------------- code 2 ------------------

```
<?php 
echo $htmlDoc = <<< HTML
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Input Field"  onClick="addField();">
    <p id="addHere"></p>
</body>
</html> 
HTML;

echo ' Entered Data is as :  '.$_POST["someName"]; 
?>
<script>
    function addField()
    {
        document.getElementById("addHere").innerHTML
        ='<form action="#" method="POST">'+
         '<input type ="text" value="default text" name="someName">'+
         '<input type ="submit" value ="Submit" >'+ 
         '</form>';
   }
</script>
```

code1 works fine 
but in code2 after submit text input field disappears why? how to retain it and retain value entered in it?

Comment: facing the same issue still i am not able to resolve it, if there is any solution let me know

Answer (score -1):

that's because your form is not by default part of your DOM document.

you are appending your form using Javascript into your DOM document using a specific event `onClick="addField();"`.

and while Form Submission is a process that sends a `POST/GET` data to the server -Server Side Process- then the server return back with some data -*refreshes the page*-, so all your DOM changes will be forgotten or restarted so to speak after this submit .

So, to work around this, you may set your form as a part of your DOM document, and control the viability by javascript.